# Opening flash web application in javafx-8 WebView

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8

I have my application in which I want to run a web application which has some Flash content. 
I am using **javafx-8**. 
I know that there was no support for flash content in javafx-2 Web-View.
In my application, the URL is opening successfully, but for flash content it is asking for Flash player(Showing that Old version of flash player detected).
I want to know if it is possible to run the flash content using javafx-8? 
If yes, then how? else how can I achieve the same?

Comment: You might want to go through [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/message/9983171#9983171).

Comment: Thanks, but in that thread last update is of Nov, 2011. So I guess that is not updated as of java-8.

Comment: You might want to re-read the thread, specially the statement which states - `As for plugins, we are not likely to ever support running plugins (except maybe applets), for security reasons.`